# How to easily find direct BigQuery table data source vs custom query data source in Data Studio Data Source list?

Tags: database, google-bigquery, looker-studio

Is it possible to easily find BigQuery data sources in Google Data Studio by direct connection from BigQuery tables vs custom query? Currently, you will have to open one by one to see if the connection is a direct one or use a custom query.

I have to deal with about 50+ connections and was wondering if there is a better way to see which one has a direct connection to the BigQuery table and which one has a custom query in use. The goal is to build custom tables for the one where we are using custom queries.

Google Data Studio Data Source Tab:

[image: Google Data Studio Data Source Tab]

Comment: It's unfortunate that this doesn't exist. It seems that you should at least be able to see the queries Data Studio is running against the data in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT. Instead, there's a service account querying tables with no audit trail at all. I created a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/214727608 .

Answer (score -1):

This is not currently supported.